# STAR PRNT SDK for android locks main ui (thread) during printing how to make it print in background

Tags: android, printing, receipt

I am using the latest STAR Micronics starPRNT SDK for android. When printing to impact printers (SP743) the sdk is blocking all ui until the print job is completed. Is there a way to have this print on a different thread or not block the ui causing what looks like the app freezing?

If it is printing a very large receipt... it will lock up the app/computer for what can be 10-20 seconds.

Looked at docs from Star as well as google search. I can find info previously about issues trying to get background printing with iOS.